# Get UTC Date in VBscript using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I got the following script that returns UTC date in the format:
`Mon, 7 Jun 2021 08:25:11 UTC`

But I would like to get `UTC` date in this format `2021-6-7T8:25:11Z`
Will this date adjust to the day light saving changes after every 6 months.

```
<%@ language="VBScript" %>
<script language='Javascript' runat='server'>
  function jsGetUTCTime() {
    var d = new Date();
    return d.toUTCString();
  }
</script>
<script language='VBScript' runat='server'>
Function getUTCTime()
    ' Use JScript to get the current GMT time stamp
    getUTCTime = jsGetUTCTime()
  End Function    
</script>
```

Comment: see: [Date.prototype.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Comment: UTC has no concept of day light savings ... so, it's not relevant

Comment: Thank you @pilchard, I am not aware of the javascript. Can you add this code to the above example. I am writing the result in VBscript as <%= getUTCTime() %>

Comment: Just replace all instances of `UTC` with `ISO`

Comment: Tried 
var d = new Date();   return d.toISOString(); it gives following error in the second line
Microsoft JScript runtime error '800a01b6'
Object doesn't support this property or method